# For Winforms (.NET), how do I create a method to check for Admin rights prior to the form loading?

Tags: c#, .net

Working on creating a WINGET Application to provide a GUI for USMT.
I want to check for Admin rights and if the program is in the right folder before the main form loads and close the application if that's not the case.

So, I create a class for this purpose so I don't have Spaghetti code in the Program class.

```
    public static class Setup
{ 
    public static bool IsAdministrator()
    {
            // Stuff
    }

    
    public static void CheckAdmin()
    {
        if (!IsAdministrator())
        {
                // Moar stuff
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the Program class, I've got this...

```
Setup.CheckAdmin();
```

But I get error IDE1007 - CheckAdmin does not exist in this context and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Are you using the correct namespace for Class `Setup` ?

Comment: I thought so, it's all running under the same namespace as program.

Comment: Could you provide more information, for example the namespaces. The class name "Setup" possibly collides with other classes. Try renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated this in a WinForms application and had no issues.  Are you calling the `CheckAdmin` function in the `Main` function of the `Program` class?

I would think it would make more sense to do this setup in the `Load` event for your form rather than the `Program` class.

Comment: Yeah, I might move it over to the load event but I can't even get the method to run. For some reason it still dosen't work for me.